# How to remove item from list which Id is not in list of Id's

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID ProductId  OrderId
-- ---------  --------
1  1          1
2  2          1
3  4          1
4  2          2
5  6          2
6  7          2
```

First of all I'm getting all ProdictId's that have the same OrderId

```
var listOfProdictids = db.OrderedProducts.Where(x => x.OrderId == 1).Select(x => x.ProductId).toArray();
```

I want it to look like 1, 2, 4

I also have a table Product

```
ID Brand      Mark
-- ---------  --------
1  Samsung    Galaxy s10
2  Apple      Iphone 7
3  Xiaomi     Mi9
4  Huawei     Honor
5  Sony       Xperia
```

What is the best way to get from database all products which Id's are 1, 2, 4?
What I think:

```
List<ProductVM> products = db.Products.Select(x => x).toList();
```

to get all the Products to list and somehow delete Id's 3 and 5 which are not in array "listOfProductids".

Or

```
List<ProductVM> products = db.Products.Where(x => x.id == listOfProductids).Select(x => x).toList();
```

Not sure that lambda `Where(x => x.id != listOfProdictids)` works.
The idea is to compare each ProductId with Id's in array. If match than select

Any idea how to do it?

the final list should look like this:

```
ID Brand      Mark
-- ---------  --------
1  Samsung    Galaxy s10
2  Apple      Iphone 7
4  Huawei     Honor
```

Update: based on answer **npinti**

If I want to do it for 2 orders should it look like this?

```
var orders = db.Orders.Select(x => x.ProductId).toArray();
to get Array with two orders 1 and 2
```

than

```
List<ProductVM> products = new List<ProductVM>();
foreach (ord o in orders)
{
// getting all product id's for first OrderId
HashSet<int> listOfProdictids = new HashSet<int>(db.OrderedProducts.Where(x => x.OrderId == o).Select(x => x.ProductId).toArray());

//getting list of products
var qwe = db.Products.Where(x => !listOfProducts.Contains(x.id)).Select(x => x).toList();

//Add list
products.Add(qwe)
}

return View (products);
```

Comment: this `.Select(x => x)` doesn't do much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and do this:
`HashSet<int> listOfProdictids = new HashSet<int>(db.OrderedProducts.Where(x => x.Id == 1).Select(x => x.ProductId).toArray());`

And then:

```
List<ProductVM> products = db.Products.Where(x => !listOfProducts.Contains(x.id)).Select(x => x).toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the order's all product ID's

```
var listOfProdictids = db.OrderedProducts.Where(x => x.OrderId == 1).Select(x => x.ProductId).ToArray();
```

You need to substract to all product's which ordered.

```
List<ProductVM> removedProducts = db.Products.Where(c=>!listOfProdictids.Contains(c=>c.Id)).ToList();
```

And remove the list from Products table.

Comment: "And remove the list from Products table" how? Is it correct: `listOfProdictids.Remove(removedProducts)` ?

Comment: You can use RemoveRange() function.  https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/addrange-removerange.aspx

Comment: `listOfProdictids.RemoveRange(removedProducts)` like this?

Comment: No, db.Products.RemoveRange(removedProducts ); You need to remove the products from Product table. Am I wrong?

Comment: I need to remoove them from List, not from DB. First of all I'm making a list of all products from Db, than I need to remove items which are in `removedProducts`